# JS array mutation

Tags: arrays, mutation, mutation-testing

Why does the first function mutate originalArr (although I created copyArr to perform methods only on that copy)? And why doesn't the second function mutate originalArr?

```
function removeSmallest(originalArr) {
  const copyArr = originalArr;
  console.log(originalArr);
copyArr.splice(copyArr.indexOf(Math.min(...copyArr)), 1);
  console.log(originalArr); //here originalArr is mutated, why?//
  return copyArr;
}

function removeSmallest(originalArr) {
  const copyArr = [];
  copyArr.push(...originalArr);
  console.log(originalArr);
copyArr.splice(copyArr.indexOf(Math.min(...copyArr)), 1);
  console.log(originalArr); //originalArr not mutated, why?//
  return copyArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays work by reference, meaning that in the first function, both `copyArr` and `originalArr` point to the same object. To copy an array and avoid this, you can use the method you used in the second function, or simply use `const copyArr = originalArr.slice()`.